# SQL Join returns duplicated query result

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite. I have 2 tables, one is a list of workers at an event, with event ID and event details.
The other table contains workers absent details, with the event ID that they were meant to attend.

I want to return a worker’s absent history (from table Absent) and include the event details sourced from any of the workers present at that event (from table Events).

I am returning what I want, however the rows are duplicated by the number of workers at the event. So, if worker John was absent from event 100, where there were 3 workers, the query would return:

```
John, Event 100, Event 100 Details
John, Event 100, Event 100 Details
John, Event 100, Event 100 Details
```

the query is:

```
 SELECT mm.WorkerID, mm.EventID, ar.EventDetails FROM AbsentTable AS mm  
 LEFT JOIN EventsTable AS ar 
 ON mm.EventID = ar.EventID 
 WHERE mm.WorkerID = :WorkerID
```

I am simplifying things as I want to figure out the cause not have my code just fixed. Why does the query return multiples? I have tried many alternatives including distinct in the select line.

Comment: Because you are joining every row in Events that matches the event in Absent.  When you only want one value returned, you have to aggregate somehow.  This is commonly done with Grouping or Distinct.

Comment: It took me a while to understand how you could get duplicates when merely joining events. It seems what you call EventsTable is *not* a table of events, but a table of workers in events. Unfortunately even filled with redundant event data. So, rather than trying to fix the query, fix the data model. (Maybe one event table, one workers table, one workers_in_events table, then either absent attributes in the latter or a separate table for absent information.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 2 tables, one is **a list of workers at an event, with event ID and event details**.

The problem is that the `EventsTable` contains several records for each event. Your join returns as many records as there were workers at the event.

One solution would be to use a subquery that selects the `DISTINCT` values that you are interrested in from the `EventsTable`, and then join it with the `AbsentTable`.

```
SELECT mm.WorkerID, mm.EventID, ar.EventDetails 
FROM AbsentTable AS mm  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT EventID, EventDetails FROM EventsTable) AS ar 
    ON mm.EventID = ar.EventID 
WHERE mm.WorkerID = :WorkerID
```

Bottom line: you have a design problem. The same information (evet details, event id) is repeated over multiple records in the `EventsTable`. It would be better to have a separate table to store the events (one record per event), and then reference the primary key of this table in the table that tracks the presence of each worker at each event.

Comment: I understand what you are saying re design issue, thanks for explaining it.